# Implement BigInt bit shifting using intrinsics over an array

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, simd, bit-shift, bigint

I'd like to implement bit shifting over a block of memory using SIMD. I have figured out this solution, that essentially follows these steps:

- Byte shifts of `shift / CHAR_BIT` using `memmove` if the shift is greater than `CHAR_BIT`
- Bit shifts iterating over each `char` of the memory block

This is essentially an O(n). I know I can just iterate over data types bigger than `char`, however I'm pretty sure this can be done even faster using intrinsics.

```
void rshift(void *self, int other, size_t size) {
    if (other < size * CHAR_BIT) {
        unsigned char *s = self,
                      *pass = calloc(2, sizeof(unsigned char));

        if (pass != NULL) {
            int chars = other / CHAR_BIT,
                bits = other % CHAR_BIT;

            if (chars > 0) {
                memmove(s + chars, s, size - chars);
                memset(s, 0, chars);
            }

            if (bits > 0) {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < size;
                     i++, pass[0] = pass[1] << (CHAR_BIT - bits)) {
                    pass[1] = s[i] & ((1 << bits) - 1);
                    s[i] = (s[i] >> bits) | pass[0];
                }
            }

            free(pass);
        }
    } else memset(self, 0, size);
}
```

I have tried taking a look at the different intrinsic operations, like `_mm_srli_si128`, that however byte shifts, doesn't bit shift.

Is there a way to implement the previous function using SIMD instructions?

Comment: Have a look at how GMP implements mpn_lshift and rshift for various SIMD ISAs, like x86 SSE2, ARM NEON. or PowerPC Altivec.   For example, https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpn/x86_64/fastsse/lshift-movdqu2.asm is x86-64 using overlapping `movdqu` loads and `ps[lr]lq` / `por` shift/or, after calculating byte offsets for the load vs. store pointers to shift in-place.

Comment: There's absolutely no need for to dynamically allocate `pass` with `char *pass = calloc(2, sizeof(unsigned char));`.  Just use `char pass[2]`.  If this function gets called many times, that can make a huge performance difference, especially in a multithreaded program.